# different vs differential (adjectives)

Tags: difference

<sub>[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q4H_XXyF71MC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=%22gender+has+traditionally+played%22&source=bl&ots=A2QPXBBNAQ&sig=iSYxD_1202AmLZC8arjweC80viA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-89OrpK3UAhWGNiYKHZJvAgMQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) *[The European Union: A Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1851688986)*. p. 139 Bottom - p. 140 Top. I, and not the book, bolded.</sub>

> Gender has traditionally played a key role in the pricing of insurance policies.
>     In 2004 an EU Directive prohibited all discrimination based on 
>   sex in the access to a supply of goods or services. In principle the 
>   Directive therefore prohibited the use of gender as a method of 
>   determining insurance premiums and benefits with regard to contracts that were entered into after 21 December 2007. However, 
>   the Directive also stated **[1.] differential** pricing could be maintained 
>   where statistical evidence supported such an approach. Insurance 
>   companies regarded this as crucial because as women drivers are 
>   statistically proven to have fewer accidents than male drivers, premiums for female insurance policies have generally been lower. In 
>   a similar way, because women live longer, men have traditionally received a higher rate from their pension annuities because their 
>   life expectancy is lower and as such their pension savings are able 
>   to produce more income over a shorter time.
>     Such continued practice of price **differentials** was subject to a 
>   review after the Belgian Constitutional Court asked the European 
>   Court of Justice to assess the validity of differential pricing. This in 
>   turn resulted in the ECJ ruling on 1 March 2011 that insurers cannot 
>   charge **[2.] different** premiums to men and women based on their 
>   gender from 21 December 2012 onwards. In the case of car insurance, the significance of this ruling is that female car insurance premiums will rise while male insurance premiums will fall. And where 
>   high costs of insurance have in the past discouraged young men 
>   from buying fast cars that are more likely to lead to road accidents, 
>   a reduction in insurance costs could worryingly result in greater 
>   purchases of high performance cars.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/differential) doesn't distinguish them, except calculus's definition of 'differential' about which I'm not asking. 'different' is synonymized with 'differential', and vice versa.

1. In 1 above, why not use 'different'? What'd change?
2. Why not use 'differential'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [different vs differential (adjectives, not nouns)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57880/different-vs-differential-adjectives-not-nouns)

Answer (score 1):

The word **different** means simply "not the same".  The adjective **differential** means "characterized by or relating to differentiation", that is,  discrimination based on specific differences or characteristics.

The premiums themselves are not making an attempt to discriminate but are the result of such discrimination/differentiation. That said, it would do no harm to call them **differential premiums** to indicate that they are part of a differential pricing strategy.

> The company has instituted differential premiums, charging different premiums to men and women based on specific statistical differences between the genders.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer:  Yes, "different" is not the same as "differential".  In addition, "differential" is a somewhat *scholarly* jargon used in mathematics and other academic fields (such as economics).  It would not normally appear in casual conversation, or in formal writing outside of these fields.

That being said, it also appears in automobile maintenance, since the *differential* [is a specific part of a car's transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mechanical_device)), as well as other technical fields that have similarly geared mechanisms.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I'm uncertain how this answers my post? 1. I wrote "calculus's definition of 'differential' about which I'm not asking". 2. I wrote in this post's title that I'm asking about them as adjectives, not nouns (your example of a car 'differential').

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal   Again, I'm just adding on to the other answer, which is the one you should accept.  Should you see *differential* used as a noun related to automobiles, you won't be confused.

Answer (score 1):

In business and economics, a **price differential** is a way of saying:
The difference in price between two or more products or services or statistics.

**differential** is **the adjective for the noun, difference.**

a price differential *=* a difference in price. Those mean the same thing.

The PRICE for product A = 50 euros
The PRICE for product B = 75 euros

***Two ways to say the same thing:***

> - The difference in price between Product A and Product B is 25 euros.
> - The price differential between the two products, A and B, is 25 euros.

So, yes, the products have **different prices or pricing** or a "difference in price". And therefore, they have a price differential.

MERRIAM WEBSTER:

Definition of differential (Entry 1 of 2)
1a : of, relating to, or **constituting a difference** : DISTINGUISHING
differential characteristics
b : making a distinction between

**Whereas** ***different*** means **not the same as**, and is only an adjective meaning that.

The reason they do not say different prices is because then one would ask: Different than what? Rather than the difference between them.

**This product** (only one) has **different prices** when sold online or in stores.

It sells in stores for 100 euros and online for 85 euros.

The store price and the online price are different from each other.

- different pricing or prices [depending on place, location, market etc.]
- differential pricing [between products, the difference between two or more products]

[Please note: this answer is not about cars.]